# How to deal with own question that resulted of a misconception?

Tags: discussion

what should I do with a [question of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555160/how-to-force-page-file-expansion-when-using-boostfile-mapping), that was the result of a misconception, and is now voted down and flagged as unclear?

It is hard to say, that I didn't put enough effort into the question, but obviously I had some wrong idea about the internal working of pagefile/pagecache/filemapping, which lead to an in the end pointless question. What should I do now?

1. vote for a delete myself
2. clarify via edit or comment, that this was the result of a misconception
3. do nothing

Comment: If you think the question is pointless, and having no answers, deleting seems reasonable.

Comment: People who vote to close high effort questions where there's an ongoing trail of progress in the comments between the asker and a potential answerer do a real **dis-service** to this site, by needlessly slowing down the process, and tossing wounded feelings into the mix.

Comment: @ChrisStratton High-effort and high-value are distinct concepts. I've been the "potential answerer" in plenty of questions where it's clear that the poster either is not interested in actually providing necessary information or just has no clue what he's doing, and the question needs to have a stake through its heart.

Answer (score 11):

I would keep the question.

Your misconception might be another person's misconception too. If that person finds your answer and you clearly explained how it was a misconception and how the software actually works, you will have paid that person a favor.

Answer (score 10):

Voting to delete is a reasonable approach.

Probably better, you could also edit and answer your own question, clarifying what was wrong with your fundamental assumption and how you solved the problem in the end.  FYI, it's entirely permissible to mark your own answer as the accepted answer, although you won't get any points.  But providing this information is a considerate thing to do that may lead to upvotes, and certainly furthers the mission of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't be so quick to recommend deletion to people. Too many deleted low-quality questions can get you question banned `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake: The question is at +-0 and of little further use due to the misconception spawning it. Just self-deleting it now should not harm him (aside from the 3 rep gained by 1 up+1 down-vote)