# Should I delete this (my) question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked this question:

[Attempted delete (or overwrite) of read-only file fails to redirect "STDERR"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400525/attempted-delete-or-overwrite-of-read-only-file-fails-to-redirect-stderr)

Dennis van Gils answered correctly, but I feel it was just an obvious mistake on my part that lead to me asking the question. So obvious, that it is probably a duplicate question.

Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can press the delete button as much as you want, but it won't work; there's an up voted answer.

Comment: Why do you think it should be deleted? If you think others might make the same mistake, and can benefit from the answer, then it's useful to the site (and future visitors) and should remain.

Comment: @Laurel - At the time I posted here on Meta, there were no upvotes to the answer.

Comment: @ZeroRequiem - As I mentioned in this post, I was asking about deleting it because I considered it was probably a duplicate. I would rather delete it myself than have it closed as a duplicate anyway. I searched for an answer first and didn't find any duplicate `questions`, but because I misunderstood what was actually happening, the answer, (which solved my issue) is probably a duplicate of answers to a different question. Since the answer has now been upvoted, deleting it seems to no longer be an option anyway. I have since upvoted and accepted that answer.

Comment: Don't delete. Just close with suitable duplicate link. Duplicates are useful to keep around, to help people find the answer easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I delete my question if it is marked as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate) (even though it's not *yet* marked as duplicate) or [Should I delete my own question after a silly mistake?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275923/should-i-delete-my-own-question-after-a-silly-mistake) or [How to deal with own question that resulted of a misconception?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254181/how-to-deal-with-own-question-that-resulted-of-a-misconception)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say no.

Your question has been upvoted, which should tell you that it's been well received by the community. The answer has also been upvoted which tells you the same thing.

The answer may come across as a simple mistake or typo to yourself - but this kind of issue could easily be reproduced unintentionally by someone not as well versed in the language. I myself have very basic knowledge in writing batch files and could easily have done that without knowing why it didn't work as expected.

The problem presented, and the answer to it (with a good explanation) is of value to the wider community and to other developers that may fall into the same issue - therefore it should stay.